# Trying to understand this simple recursion code

Tags: recursion

Please help me understand this simple recursion. I'm very new to programming, so I'm wondering how exactly this happens step by step.

I'm trying to learn recursion, but I'm stuck with the addition of "+"

```
function foo($bar) {
  if ($bar == 1) return 1;
  elseif ($bar == 0) return 0;
  else return foo($bar - 1) + foo($bar - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to understand recursion I find it helps a lot to write down each individual case for a specific parameter and then build your understanding from there.

So let's take the example of `foo(3)`

foo(3) -> we don't hit either base case, so our function now wants to return

```
foo(2) + foo(1)
```

First we need to get foo(2)

foo(2) -> Again no base case, so we return

```
foo(1) + foo(0)
```

foo(1) = 1 and foo(0) = 0 (these are our base cases) so we see that

```
foo(2) = 1 + 0
```

Now our look at foo(3) is resolved to

foo(3) -> (1 + 0) + foo(1)

foo(1) = 1, so we can finally see that

foo(3) -> (1 + 0) + 1 = 2

You have to remember that recursion is basically building a "tree" of function calls - it's going to go as far down the tree as possible, and then come up one level and see what else it has to do to continue. I'm not sure how clear this is but hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

it's simple really (once you wrap your head around it). In the last line you are calling the function foo twice and adding their return values together.

here is a sample trace

```
call 1:
    foo(3)
    return foo(2) + foo(1)

    call 2:
        foo(2)
        return foo(1) + foo(0)

        call 3:
            foo(1)
            return 1

    unrolls to call 2:
        return 1 + foo(0)

        call 4:
            foo(0)
            return 0

    unrolls to call 2 again:
        return 1 + 0

unrolls to call 1:
    return 1 + foo(1)

    call 5:
        foo(1)
        return 1

unrolls to call 1 again:
    return 1 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The first invocation of *foo()* ends up calling two additional invocation of *foo()*.  Each of those two in turn calls two of their own, and so on.

**First Iteration**

foo()

**Second Iteration**

foo()  foo()

**Third Iteration**

foo() foo() foo() foo()

etc.

So, if foo() does not hit one of the termination conditions, it always calls itself twice more.

It may be instructive to add a variable indicating the call depth and having foo() print out its arguments including the call depth argument.